# Flex: How Do I Reference the System Font?

Tags: apache-flex, font-family

I've embedded a font in my component. All of the text in the component uses the embedded font. But, I want a button to use the standard system font. How do I set the button's fontFamily to the system font?

```
<mx:Button label="Hello" fontFamily="?" />
```

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify any font family style, and it will fall back on the defaults of the framework.

Look at the fontFamily style documentation here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TextInput.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#top

The default font for the Halo theme is "Verdana". The default font for the Spark theme is "Arial".